# Any way to color margins, padding, and line-height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, developer-tools

I'd like to be able to hypothetically click a bookmarklet and have the line-heights, margins, and padding of each element on the page have a color. Much like development tools in any browser, but for the entire page at once.

Does this option currently exist in a browser, or is there a way to add color to these element properties?

Comment: Why not just press F-12?

Comment: @Diodeus I'm on a Mac, with Chrome as the preferred browser. What's the intended result of pressing f12? I'm attempting to color all elements on the page, instead of hovering over elements one-by-one in the dev tools.

Comment: Take a look at TamperMonkey: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en

Comment: Note that you can't change the colors of paddings and margins in a HTML element. If you need to do so, you will need to add extra markup to the HTML that you can give those alternate colors. (Of course that might not be a problem, but I'm just saying you can't simply provide CSS to do that.)

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for the response. I took a look at the Chrome inspector code. I think they're creating the additional elements (margins & padding) in javascript on the fly for each element in the DOM. I'm assuming this isn't possible for now. Thanks again!